# Get file depending on extension and directory in R

Tags: r

Does anyone knows the way to do this script In **python** but in `R` :

```
directory="my_directory"
extension=".txt"
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    if filename.endswith(extension):
```

but in `R` ? I have difficult to find it for `R` ..
Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried? There are functions in R that are called `list.files` and `endsWith` that are nearly identical to the python equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not enough reputation to comment to the solution of @felipe-alvarenga which I second, but if the files are of the same structure you can additionally merge them conventiently with the `data.table` package:

```
if (!require(data.table)) install.packages("data.table")
files <- list.files(path = 'my_directory', pattern = "*.txt")
DT <- rbindlist(lapply(files, function(x) cbind(fread(x), gsub(".txt", "", x))))
```

Comment: Welcome! Glad we could help you :)

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
list.files(path = 'my_directory', pattern = '\\.txt')
```

Comment: Thank you for your help